# How do I restart a specific version of my PostgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql, bash, ubuntu

When I ssh onto my server (that has a PostgreSQL database) and enter this command in my bash shell...

```
pg_lsclusters
```

...this is my output:

```
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner     Data directory               Log file
9.3 main    xxxx down   <unknown> /var/lib/postgresql/9.3/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.3-main.log
9.4 main    xxxx online postgres  /var/lib/postgresql/9.4/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.4-main.log
11  main    xxxx down   postgres  /var/lib/postgresql/11/main  /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11-main.log
```

However when I go to restart the server by this command:

```
service postgresql restart
```

It says its restarting version 9.4:

```
Restarting PostgreSQL 9.4 database server
```

How do I restart PostgreSQL version 11 server?

Comment: Are using UBUNTU as OS?

Comment: No that is telling you the  `psql`  client is from version 11.3. Ubuntu Postgres packaging will use the latest version of `psql` you have installed as the default to connect with.  At the command line do `pg_lsclusters` and add the results as update to your question.

Comment: OK I updated my question above with the `pg_lsclusters` command. I see the version 11 of PostgreSQL is down - I take it that's why it wont restart

Answer (score 1):

you can use `pg_ctlcluster`

```
$ pg_ctlcluster 
Usage: /usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster <version> <cluster> <action> [-- <pg_ctl options>]

#status
$ sudo pg_ctlcluster 11 main status
pg_ctl: server is running (PID: 1111)
/usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/postgres "-D" "/var/lib/postgresql/11/main" "-c" "config_file=/etc/postgresql/11/main/postgresql.conf"

#restart
sudo pg_ctlcluster 11 main restart
```

Comment: When I do `sudo pg_ctlcluster 11 main status` I get: `Error: Could not find pg_ctl executable for version 11`

Comment: check the files inside this directory: `/usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin`